# How does a spaceship respond to a sling?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, rigid-body-dynamics, rocket-science

1. If you are in a spaceship and you spin a sling with a rock in it, does the spaceship rotate in the opposite direction as the sling with the same angular, kinetic energy as the sling?
2. If the sling is released while spinning, and the rock flies off and hits the wall of the spaceship, does the spaceship obtain linear velocity from stopping the rock?

Answer (score 1):

> If you are in a spaceship and you spin a sling with a rock in it, does the spaceship rotate in the opposite direction as the sling with the same angular, kinetic energy as the sling?

(I'm assuming that before spinning, everything is at rest).

*Something* else needs to have opposite angular momentum.  It could be that the spacecraft is spinning, or that the spacecraft fired some thrusters, or that something inside the spacecraft is moving or spinning.

> If the sling is released while spinning, and the rock flies off and hits the wall of the spaceship, does the spaceship obtain linear velocity from stopping the rock?

When it stops, they exchange momentum.  So the spacecraft will undergo some acceleration from the impact.  But presumably whatever started the sling also exchanged momentum and accelerated the ship in the opposite direction. As long as nothing is leaving the spaceship, then the center of mass of the system won't accelerate.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

Imagine standing on ice and whirling a rock in a sling around your head. You might imagine that the sling points toward the center of rotation. Pulling the rock inward supplies the centripetal force that keeps the rock moving in a circle. This is true, as far as it goes.

But you start with a stationary rock and spin it up. To do this, your and moves in a small circle. The sling points mostly toward the center or rotation, but also a little forward. This forward component makes the rock circle faster.

The rock is pulling on you. You feel an outward force from the rock. Since the rock lags a little behind your hand, it pulls backward on you. Since you are standing on ice, you begin to spin backward. You are much larger than the rock, so your rotational velocity is small. But the rock and you have the same angular momentum.

You also travel in a small circle as the rock travels in a big circle. You are slightly on one side of the axis of rotation. The rock is farther on the other side. You mutually pull each other toward the center.

Suppose you are standing in a spaceship as you spin the up rock. Your feet exert a torque on the spaceship. The spaceship begins to spin.

---

While standing on ice, you let go of the rock. You and the rock are traveling in opposite directions, tangent to your circles, at the moment you let go. You both keep on traveling in those directions.

In a spaceship, the spaceship travels in a tiny circle as you whirl the rock in a big circle. When you let go, the spaceship and rock keep going. When the rock collides with the wall of the spaceship, both come to a stop.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to both questions depends on whether or not you are floating in the spaceship (not touching the floor/walls) or standing on the floor under the influence of some gravity.

If you are floating:

1. your body will rotate in the other direction to conserve angular momentum and the spaceship will not be affected at all.
2. When you throw the rock, you will be propelled backward to conserve linear momentum. When the rock strikes the wall of the ship, it will impart some momentum in an approximately elastic collision. However, you are flying backward slowly with the same momentum as the rock and will eventually hit the other wall.

If you are standing on the floor due to, let's say, artificial gravity.

1. When you spin the sling, your body will twist, your feet will exert force against the floor, and some torque on the spaceship will result. The acceleration of the ship in response will be quite negligible due to its large mass. If you try this out on a smaller scale however, by spinning something over your head while sitting on a swivel chair, the chair will spin in the opposite direction.
2. If you throw the rock while standing, there will be no effect.  Because the total momentum of the whole system (you the rock and the spaceship does not change).